# Retrieve song lyrics with python and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the lyrics of songs of this page

https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1986778

I've never used bs4 before so I dont know how to face the problem, I tried finding all the tables, all the paragraphs or all the text with a specific font, but I cant get it to work (I couldn't write a piece of code that does what I want to do).

**off topic**: this is how I get the urls to the songs.

This url has a list with all the songs of that artist
https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letras=22997

my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

url = 'https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letras=22997'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a')
song_links = [link for x link links if ('>Letras de Massacre' in str(link)) ]
```

which I think it isnt the most elegant script ever, I had the same problem here, I tried to get the links finding the table which has them, but after some trial and error I noticed that all the song links say '>Letras de Massacre' in them.

thanks for taking your time to read this!

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @SuperStew That I don't know how to get a string with the lyrics of the song in the url I posted, using python and bs4. Maybe the issue is trivial to someone, but it isn't for me and can't find a way to do it.

Comment: I didn't post the html of the page, but I pasted the url

Comment: As you have found and chosen your working solution, I've taken out mine @Juanig. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the url you link has a bunch of other urls, which is where the lyrics are. You'll need to use requests to GET each one of those. I used this as an example
https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1103460

Now you can quickly scrape the lyrics like so.

```
#assuming you already set the url
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
lyrics=soup.find_all('p')[0]
```

This will get you a string with the lyrics, along with some linebreak and paragraph tags that you'll need to parse out. Should be easy to do with re or whatever.